# $X =\{a \mid f(a) \neq 0\}$ for some $f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, prove that $X$ is an algebraic set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I had this question in my assignment.

For $n = 1$, I found a counter example ($f(x)= x$, $X$ is uncountable and hence not algebraic as algebraic sets in $A$ are finite).

I wonder is the question still true with added condition that $n>1$?

Comment: What is $k$? Your reasoning doesn't work in finite fields.

Comment: k is any closed field.

Comment: You mean algebraically closed I guess? You should mention that in your question. Note also that algebraically closed field need not be uncountable (but they are infinite, so your counterexample is still correct).

Comment: so, what about the rest of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your are describing the complement of an hypersurface in $\mathbb A^n$. This is not $\mathbb A^n$ if e.g you work over an algebraically closed field, and on the other hand it has dimension $n$. Any other algebraic variety as $\mathbb A^n$ has dimension less that $n$, so this is never an algebraic variety, considered as a subset of $\mathbb A^n$.

On the other hand, it is an algebraic subset of $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ with coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n, t$, defined by the equation $tf - 1 = 0$.

Taking your example, the set $\{ x \in \mathbb A^1 : x \neq 0\}$ is isomorphic to an algebraic variety of $\mathbb A^2$ given by the hyperbola $xy = 1$.